# In WCF Service, I need to send the DataMember based on the condition. How to do that?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

For example:

```
Public class TEST
{
      [DataMember]
       public string EMPName
       {
        get; set;
        }
}
```

I need EMPName to be the part of the object which is the output response, but based on some condition and I need to write that condition in the service function I am calling.

e.g: If the EMPName contains 'Jolie' then only keep it the part of the output object otherwise don't send it with the output object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **ShouldSerialize** property in your TESTclass.
Include the line below in your TESTclass:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeEMPName() { return EMPName.Contains("Jolie"); }
```

Hope it helps